# Java Android - new class function defined inside method?

Tags: java, android

Hello i have recently started programming in java especially on android, since im new to java , i found something that i dont understand.

```
theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String pickedLanguage = "Your favorite programming language is : " + String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,pickedLanguage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

**What i dont understand:**

- The method `setOnItemClickListener` contains in its parameter list a new class ? how is this possible ? whats going on ? i just read a tutorial about classes and it says class should be in a single file and should have the same name as the file , and basically what does this mean ? the sample code i pasted says create a new instance from this function which belongs to adapter view ? i thought you can create only a new object not just a function from object, i basicaly dont understand the whole code , how is it possible that there is a new class defined inside method ?

Comment: This is an anonymous class, google it.

Answer (score 3):

It's called anonymous classes and are commonly used to give interface implementation to a method when its called, without creating a separate class that implement the interface for later instantiate it.

In this case the method `setOnItemClickListener` receive an instance of interface `OnItemClickListener`, we can create a separate class that implement that interface and to later instantiate or just provide to the method an anonymous implementation at the moment of calling.

You can find more detail [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)